# Cannot plot graph in Matlab '??? Error using ==> mtimes' (Inner matrix dimensions must agree.)

Tags: matlab

when i type this equation in MatLab, I get the following error:

```
x=linspace(0,8*pi,1000);
y=x*sin(x);

??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with plotting.

But you want element-wise multiplication. e.g., .* instead of *

x=linspace(0,8*pi,1000);
y=x.*sin(x);

http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/www/matlab/imatlab/node10.html